# Visual Studio - Close a console app for build and reopen after?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We currently use a background queue, which is in the form of an .exe on dev machines, and it is a source of frustration having to close and reopen the .exe whenever the code is built.

Is it possible, as part of the dev build process, to have VS close the background queue, build, and then re-open it?

Comment: Have you tried running a batch file pre and post build to kill and start the queue ?

Comment: @auburg I haven't as I wasn't sure of what approach to take, I will now look into running a batch pre and post build!

Comment: Why does the queue need to be closed? Suggests a problem with the queue if it requires a restart to pick up changes.

Comment: @ManoDestra The queue project lies within the VS solution, so there are complaints that the exe is open when the compiler attempts to compile the project.

Comment: But surely, it's only running locally? You shouldn't have the queue running as a standalone exe whilst you're developing. You should only run it up when you're working on your other project. And if you need to work on the queue project, then you'd have it closed anyway, surely? You could perhaps use a custom build script in VS to handle this, I guess, if you wish it to be automatic rather than manual, but it could be prone to error.

Comment: The current set is up how I have described. I'm not looking to change this for my employer, but merely instead overcome a frustration.